# How to send HTTP POST request and process the data on android?

Tags: java, android, post, response

I am a beginner in Android development, and I want to link my app to a database.

I made a PHP script which works as intended, but i am stuck on this problem for days.

I want to send a HTTP request to my page and then process the response, but I always get stuck somewhere, because I really don't have clue what I'm doing here. The most answers i found in this topic are outdated.

Here is what my URL looks like(simplified):
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/myapp/api.php?action=add&name=johndoe

What is the correct way to send this data to the server and where can i catch the response; how should I process it?

My current steps:

- I am doing everything from a thread and it actually gets called
- I tried multiple ways with Stream writers and readers, but no success.

Thanks for any help in advance, if someone can show me a code or at least give me some info i would be really helpful. Android documentation is really confusing for me, so i just can't move forward alone at this point.

Answer (score 0):

For http requests I use [okhttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/).
You can add it as a dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.2") 
}
```

Or download it and throw it into the libs folder.